# Zebra ZM400 Prints a blank label before print

Tags: zebra-printer

I have a ZM400 industrial printer. When I send a print job to print a one label using Z Designer, It prints a blank label before the print job happens. Print job happens perfectly but waste a one label. Can anyone point me why this happening. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of calibration of system.

Just calibrate your system manually i.e. put sticker size manually instead of auto. This will solve your problem.

Comment: I just calibrated it and it fixed the issue.